# How can I use an array as input for FILTER function in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

So this might be trivial, but it's kinda hard to ask. I'd like to `FILTER` a range based other `FILTER` results.

I'll try to explain from inside out (related to image below):

- I use filter to find all `name`s for given `id` (the results are joined in column B). This works fine and returns an array of values. This is the **inner** `FILTER`.
- I want to use this array of `name`s to find all `value`s for them using another **outer** `FILTER`.

In other words: *Find maximum `value` for all `name`s for given `id`.*

Here is what I've figured:

```
=MAX(FILTER(J:J, CONTAINS???(FILTER(G:G, F:F = A2), I:I)))
                 ^--- imaginary function returning TRUE for every value in I 
                      that is contained in the array

=MAX(FILTER(J:J, I:I = FILTER(G:G, F:F = A2)))
                     ^--- equal does not work here when filter returns more than 1 value

=MAX(FILTER(J:J, REGEXMATCH(JOIN(",", FILTER(G:G, F:F = A2)), I:I)))
                 ^--- this approach WORKS but is ineffective and slow on 10k+ cells
```

[image]
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k5lOUYMLebkmU7X2SLmzWGiDAVR3u3CSAF3dYZ_VnKE

I hope to find better `CONTAINS` function then the `REGEXMATCH`/`JOIN` combo, or to do the task using other approach.

Answer (score 0):

try this in **A2** cell (after you delete everything in **A2:C** range):

```
=SORTN(SORT({INDIRECT("F2:F"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), 
 TRANSPOSE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({F2:G}, 
 "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"), "offset 1"),,999^99)), " ", ",")), 
 VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("G2:G"&COUNTA(F2:F)+1), I2:J, 2, 0)}, 1, 1, 3, 0), 999^99, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image: 0]